# Java JNI Error in VS Code on MacOS Ventura

Tags: java, macos, vscode-debugger

To start learning Java on my MacOS I downloaded the Java SE Development Kit 19.0.1 from Oracle on my MacBook Pro 2018 running on Ventura.
I then configured the Java Home Path according to some YT Videos.
I also installed to Java Extension Pack from the Visual studio website.

In class we wrote a simple Hello World Java Program. Everytime I try to run a java program in vs code I keep getting a JNI error. I've already checken whether my javac and java Versions are the same, both are 19.0.1

This is the error I keep getting:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error decoding percent encoded characters
        at java.base/sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(ParseUtil.java:218)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.FileURLMapper.getPath(FileURLMapper.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.FileURLMapper.exists(FileURLMapper.java:73)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URLClassPath.java:826)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:771)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:765)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:764)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:738)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:502)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:485)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:484)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:452)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:321)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:757)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:790)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:685)
```

Before I installed the JDK from Oracle vs code suggested a link for a JDK that I'd previously installed: Basically the Eclipse Temurin JDK.

I thought that maybe they had clashed. I delete the temurin jdk, but I still keep getting the error. (Maybe it's not entirely deleted, I had to search it with the Terminal because Finder wouldn't show me where it was)

Deleted the temurin in the Terminal this way:
sudo rm -r temurin-11.jdk

This is the Java Version I have:
java version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)

This is the Javac Version:
javac 19.0.1

What I did to configure Java_HOME variable:

$echo $JAVA_HOME
$/usr/libexec/java_home
Output: zsh: no such file or directory: $/usr/libexec/java_home
/usr/libexec/java_home
Output: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home
echo $SHELL
Output: /bin/zsh
touch ~/.zshenv
open ~/.zshenv
source ~/.zshenv
echo $JAVA_HOME
Output: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home

I've tried running the some of the Codes we've been provided in class on the linux computers of the our Institute, they work perfectly fine there.

Example of Code:

```
public class Testen {   
    public static void main( String[] args){ 
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Another Example:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello, world!"); //dies ist eine Anweisung, also wie im Shell ein KOmmando
    }
} /* Dieses Programm gibt eine Begrüßung aus und endet  */
```

Any Program I Run gives me a JNI error.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this error, my problem was that the path where my .class file was in, had emojis in it. Try to put your .java file into the Documents folder, this worked for me. Check if your path doesn't contain any special characters such as emojis or characters like ä, ö and ü. Try to make your path purely alphanumerical.

Comment: Could have been one of the most irritating and simple errors. Thank god I found your answer. Saved a ton of time.